# jQuery Mobile Navigate Between Pages using Form

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a form using select values, I'd like to make each option works as a link. How can I do it?

```
        <form>
            <label for="direction">Select Direction:</label>
            <select name="dir" id="dir">
                <option value="1"><a href="#page2">N</a></option>
                <option value="2"><a href="#page3">S</option>
            </select>
            </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Confirm">
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Listen to `submit` event to retrieve `select` value and then change page.

Remove anchor tag from option, and put page ID in value `value="#pageID"`.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#pageID", function () {
  $("#formID").on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var page = $("#selectID").val();
    $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", page);
  });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/awepu3qc/)**

Comment: First of all, thanks! I was wondering if you can take a look in the code and see where I am wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/576kzap5/

Comment: @user2397621 wrap code in head, and you've missed closing page div. http://jsfiddle.net/576kzap5/4/

Comment: doesn't seem to work here. I had changed no wrap, onLoad, onDemand, and I closed the div at the end. http://jsfiddle.net/576kzap5/5/
Can you help me where is it wrong now? It seems to make the transition, but to a blank page =(

Comment: @user2397621 http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/awepu3qc/ I forgot `e.preventDefault()` also many divs weren't properly closed.

Comment: Thank you @Omar! About the divs, I'll properly close all of them in my local document.